# How do I use Fluidsynth for MIDI playback in SDL_Mixer?

Tags: c++, windows, sdl, midi, sdl-mixer

I've been trying to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864603/sdl-mixer-midi-volume-issues-on-windows-vista-7) by using FluidSynth with SDL_Mixer.

I am using the latest versions, SDL_Mixer 1.2.12 (DLL from official website) and FluidSynth 1.1.6 (DLL from [here](http://www.zdoom.org/files/fluidsynth.7z)) on Windows, which should work with each other.

I've renamed the FluidSynth DLL to "libfluidsynth.dll" in accordance with SDL_Mixer and placed it next to the "SDL_Mixer.dll". I've passed the absolute and relative path to the sf2 through SDL_SetSoundFonts(), SDL_SOUNDFONTS, and even SDL_putenv(). I've tried putting the call before and after Mix_OpenAudio().

However, when I play back a MIDI file through SDL_Mixer, I still only get the default Timidity++ output. Mix_GetError() returns no messages. What am I missing?